# What does 'lift up' mean in a religious context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, religion

I came across this tweet from Sen Rob Portman from Ohio, [referring to the death of Otto Warmbier](https://twitter.com/senrobportman?lang=en),

> His passing today is a loss for Ohio and for all of us. Jane and I are ***lifting up*** the Warmbier family in our prayers at this difficult time.

I have tried both the Dictionary.com and Collins dictionary, but the closest meaning of this phrase I could find is 'raise up, hoist'. But I think it's somehow off the mark in the mentioned context, as we can't literally raise up people in the prayer. Unless it means figuratively to 'hoist' people to heaven, which I can find no source to bear out. Therefore, I was curious about people's take on this question.

Comment: The clause you should be looking up is 'lift up *in prayer*'. So, holding up to God by praying for them.

Comment: Part of the liturgy from the Book of Common Prayer is:  
    Priest: Lift up your hearts.
    People: We lift them up to the Lord.

Comment: In Psalms, lift up is originally more like carrying [Psalm 121: *I will lift up my eyes to the hills*]. We are carrying Otto's family high up in our minds as we pray for them. Thus, we lift the wishes spiritually to the heavens for immediate receipt and consolation, for the unimaginable loss of a child.

Comment: The OED gives a rare or obsolete meaning of 'lift' as ' To bear, support.', it is possible that, what with the King James version etc, ecclesiastical use tends to the old school.

Comment: It's another thing people say when other people die and they want to sound like they care.

Comment: It comes from the practice of lifting ones hands in prayer: https://stmichaellivermore.com/blog/lifting-hands-prayer-mass

Answer (score 1):

**To lift up**

OED

> **5.** transitive. **In various phrases chiefly Hebraisms, or in the Hebrew manner.**

(Hence the biblical/religious reference)

> **b. to lift (up) the hand(s),(b) in prayer,**
>
> 1807   J. Robinson Archæol. Græca iii. v. 222   In praying it was likewise customary to lift up the hands towards heaven.

I suspect that the NP "our hands" is understood.

Comment: It's an echo of the wave offering of OT times. It's bringing a request for help to God's notice. (The NT makes it plain that God of course knows what we/others need before we ask, but cooperation in prayer is still required and powerful.)

Comment: Or, as Ambrose Bierce said: "To ask that the laws of the universe be annulled in behalf of a single petitioner confessedly unworthy.”

Answer (score -1):

In some cultures it is believed that saying a prayer is inappropriate because to say something to someone implies that you are on the same level with the person to which you are talking.  Our prayers rise as in the symbol of the smoke from the burning incense on the altar of incense in the tabernacle. Sen. Portman was simply saying he and his wife were lifting up prayers and the subjects of those prayers were the Warmbier family.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).